# Handle SQL injection in HQL order by clause

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, sql-order-by, code-injection

is there a simple way to handle SQL injection in Hibernate HQL order by clause. Named params obviously doesn't work for it.

**EDIT:**

Feel free to post your way of handling this problem. I want to see other people's solutions and teach from them.

Thanks for any suggestions and solutions.

Comment: Why not use nhibernate with linq?

Comment: @Dave Hi, I'm using Java so linq is not accessible for me.

Comment: I should have picked that up rom hibernate, rather than nHibernate! Good luck resolving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the Hibernate criteria API instead of HQL.

The criteria API check that the order criterium refers a valid property.

if you try someting like that:

```
public void testInjection() {
    String orderBy = "this_.type desc, type";

    Criteria crit = this.getSession().createCriteria(DemoEntity.class);
    crit.addOrder(Order.asc(orderBy));      
    crit.list();
}
```

You will get an `QueryException: "could not resolve property this_ of de.test.DemoEntity"`
thrown by AbstractPropertyMapping.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, but I'm working on running project where I can't switch to the criteria API. So I'm searching for exactly what you point but in HQL.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with solution which I wanted to avoid. I've implemented map where key is what's user see in URL and value is column(s) in DB which is after ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate uses PreparedStatement's which already gaurd against SQL injection. In a PreparedStatment, arguments are bound to the statement rather than having a plain text SQL statement being issued. You should not need to worry about SQL injection when using hibernate.

Here is a thread that ensures that hibernate is safe from SQL injection [Click Here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=960817&start=0&postdays=0&postorder=asc).

Comment: Yes, thats' true, but if you use setParameter in PreparedStatment SQL looks like  <...order by 'name'...> and result is not ordered, because it should look like <...order by name...>. I'm searching for simple way to avoid to manage some table of allowed fields.